# Display the list of dates in a proper format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, datetime

I am running this code to get a date

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int(start_date.day), int((end_date - start_date).days), 90):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2016, 1, 1)
end_date = date.today()
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    x = list(single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    print(x)
```

and its giving me this output

```
['2', '0', '1', '6', '-', '0', '1', '-', '0', '2']
['2', '0', '1', '6', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '1']
['2', '0', '1', '6', '-', '0', '6', '-', '3', '0']
['2', '0', '1', '6', '-', '0', '9', '-', '2', '8']
['2', '0', '1', '6', '-', '1', '2', '-', '2', '7']
['2', '0', '1', '7', '-', '0', '3', '-', '2', '7']
['2', '0', '1', '7', '-', '0', '6', '-', '2', '5']
['2', '0', '1', '7', '-', '0', '9', '-', '2', '3']
['2', '0', '1', '7', '-', '1', '2', '-', '2', '2']
['2', '0', '1', '8', '-', '0', '3', '-', '2', '2']
['2', '0', '1', '8', '-', '0', '6', '-', '2', '0']
['2', '0', '1', '8', '-', '0', '9', '-', '1', '8']
['2', '0', '1', '8', '-', '1', '2', '-', '1', '7']
['2', '0', '1', '9', '-', '0', '3', '-', '1', '7']
['2', '0', '1', '9', '-', '0', '6', '-', '1', '5']
['2', '0', '1', '9', '-', '0', '9', '-', '1', '3']
['2', '0', '1', '9', '-', '1', '2', '-', '1', '2']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, I want the list to display in date in a proper date format, something like this [2019-12-12, 2019-09-13, ...]

My goal is to create a list of dates, which I will be using in Gmail to search for emails. So it needs to be in a format that Gmail understands. My current level of coding/python is at beginners so it might be a very simple solution that I am currently missing. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you make a list of the characters?  All you need is the formatting you already did correctly:

```
print(single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: I want to use all the output from that list to search in Gmail. So created a variable to store the output in a list.

Comment: No, you broke each formatted string into separate characters.  See any tutorial on list management and iteration for how to build a list of successively generated values.

Comment: Is there a way I can display the last value of the output similar to  what a list does?

Comment: *Specify* what you mean.  Give an example.  Edit that into your question.  Please refer to the posting guidelines to get used to what goes where in a well-structured question.

Comment: Apologise. I am kind of new to the coding, so asking the right question had been difficult. What I meant was, now that the formatting is taken care of. I was wondering if there is way to just print the last value of the output. Similar to what can be done in a list for eg: list(1,2,3)[-1].displays plays the output 3.

Comment: Since the above output is not a list. Is there a way to display the last value of the output.

Comment: You're still not specifying what you want.  My solution above displays *each* of the outputs, one at a time.  This includes the last one.  If you need a list of these dates, I again refer you to appropriate tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
x = [sd.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for sd in daterange(start_date, end_date)]
print(x)
```

output:

```
['2016-01-02', '2016-04-01', '2016-06-30', '2016-09-28', '2016-12-27', '2017-03-27', '2017-06-25', '2017-09-23', '2017-12-22', '2018-03-22', '2018-06-20', '2018-09-18', '2018-12-17', '2019-03-17', '2019-06-15', '2019-09-13', '2019-12-12']
```